# R calling Cpp code: global variables not re-initialized

Tags: c++, r, global-variables

I am writing a R package which call a Cpp program at one point.

I am not an expert in programming in R and Cpp, but I will try to explain the problem as clearly as possible:

- The Cpp code creates some global variables an modify it afterward (I known it is bad...).
- When I open R and run one time my R function from my package everything is fine. But when I re-run it, it seems that the global variables creating by the Cpp code are not re-initialized and the modified value are used instead. I other words, it seems that the global variables created by Cpp 'stay in memory' and are not re-written when I call the program again.

I hope my problem is clear enough and that someone can explain me why it does behave this way. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you need the global variables for anyway, if you want to have them freshly initialized for each function call?

Answer (score 2):

You do in fact explain that somewhat poorly, but in essence you need to understand that

- a function call is just temporary, whether it involves C++ from R or not
- so whatever you set *will just disappear afterwards* unless you, say return a value, or...
- if you want to maintain "state", create a proper class, instantiate it first and then make calls using the object. Rcpp can help with the R / C++ interfacing.

Comment: A function call may be temporary, but the OP refers to *global variables* which will, unless the shared library that contains the C++ code is reloaded, keep their values. ?

Comment: Yes, but as I understand what OP said, the C++ is called from R and there is only a limited 'call a function, return' interface.  Which can of course be used to start stateful things but that does not happen by default.

Comment: I think krlmlr re-phrased well by point. What I naively understand from my problem is that there are some global variables in the shared library which are then modified by the C++ function called by R.

Comment: But doing library(mypackage) does not re-initialize the value of the global variables.

Comment: Create a source file. Make the globals `static`. Add setter functions, or an `init()` _that you will call from R upon package load_. These things don't happen automagically.